# 3-tier architecture correctness

Tags: java, architecture, 3-tier

I  have a project implemented in a (flawed) 3-tier architecture. My job is making it more generic so that it would be easy to add a new database into the project.

Concrete: there is a databaseFacade for an SQL database and i have to make it more generic so we can add multiple databases very easy. In this case writing it to a CSV file.

My idea in the database layer was to make a interface where all the methods are defined. Then having the database facade (depending which you want to use) implementing this interface so that it becomes more generic. 
Then i have some kind of DBmanager class. This DBmanager class will read out a config file so he knows what database to use. Based on this info he will create an instance of the interface and return this to the application layer.

However this is where I don't know if i'm correct. The application layer now has a DBmanager class (where everything is correctly encapsulated only 1 method is public for returning the facade) and after that the DBfacade.

Any thoughts about the correctness of this? Since I'm having doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a PHP system ([Moodle](http://moodle.org/)) use almost exactly this pattern and it works fine. All that happens is that the DB type is specified as a config variable and the concrete DB access class is instantiated as the global DB manager object, providing the facade methods e.g. get_records(), which returns a standardised array of row objects. Arguable whether you would call this facade or adapter, but that's hardly a worry.

I'd say go for it with your current plan. You seem to have decoupled the layers properly and understood the purpose of the patterns. Also, the way your low level (DB) and high level (application controller) components both depend on a single DB facade interface in the middle is a good example of [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), so bonus points for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct approach.  One minor quibble is that your DBManager actually follows the [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern, and so should be called DatabaseFacadeFactory, assuming that your facade class is called DatabaseFacade.

As you become more comfortable with Java, check out [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/).  It provides a lot of tools and techniques that automatically handle situations such as this, and remove the need for much of the boilerplate code.  For more information, see [dependency-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection).

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems legit. I'm not an expert in software architecture yet, but your description describes similar concept in comparison to how JDBC was designed.